# Status bar has white text and black icons

Tags: ios, objective-c

What can cause a status bar to have white text and black icons?
Dark mode support is disabled via `UIUserInterfaceStyle` key in the app plist set to `Light`. Status bar color is setup like this in the root controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        return UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent;
    } else {
        return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
    }
}
```

Is `UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent` causing this glitch?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. This happened after direct assignment of the root controller and had something to do with the app windows.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = controller
```

Any action with the window (showing the keyboard, etc.) fixed everything. My solution was to add `makeKeyAndVisible`

```
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```